# Event Handler for closing modal popups

Tags: javascript, selenium, event-handling, modal-dialog

I'm doing some selenium web testing and on this one site I'm automating a modal popup would sometimes show up randomly and would prevent me from grabbing other elements. I know there are built in Selenium methods for closing the popup like alert().dismiss() but this would mean I know when the popup would show up and I don't it shows up at random.

I would like to know how to attach an event listener for when these modal popups show up and have a callback that would close out of it. please and thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you know where is the code that triggers the popup, you can simply inject few line of javascript in webdriver and nullify the popup.

As an example, if the popup appears after a couple of seconds and is triggered by the following code:

`setTimeout(function () {
  showModal()
}, 5000);`

you could override the modal function in the webpage with the following (Java) code:

`driver.executeScript("showModal = function () {}");`

the next time the modal is executed this will trigger an empty function.